# Return a FileResult from a byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core API. The API is database driven.

I am storing images in the database, my `ArtistImage.cs` entity looks like this:

**ArtistImage.cs**

```
public class ArtistImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }

    public int ArtistId { get; set; }

    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
}
```

How can I convert a `byte[]` to something like: `return File("~/Images/photo.jpg", "image/jpeg");` where that would simply serve the image?

I want avoid writing the byte array to a local system file first.

**What I have Tried**

I have tried the method below, but apparently, I can't use `File` like that.

```
public class ImagesService : IImagesService 
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public ImagesService(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<FileResult> GetArtistImageAsync(int imageId)
    {
      byte[] imageBytes = await context
        .ArtistImages
        .Where(ai => ai.Id == imageId)
        .Select(ai => ai.Data)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

      return System.IO.File(imageBytes, "image/jpg", "test");
    }
}
```

[image: what I have tried]

Comment: Perhaps have your method return `Task<IActionResult>`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are mixing up controller helper methods and trying to access them from an unrelated service.

I would suggest you refactor the service to return the byte array

*ImagesService*

```
public Task<byte[]> GetArtistImageAsync(int imageId) {
    return context.ArtistImages
            .Where(ai => ai.Id == imageId)
            .Select(ai => ai.Data)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

and then have the controller return the FileResult

*Controller*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction(....) {
    //...

    var bytes = await imagesService.GetArtistImageAsync(imageId);
    return File(bytes,  "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: `File` seems to be a method here, and not the static class from the `System.IO` namespace. Where does it come from?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes `File` in this case is a method on `ControllerBase`.

Comment: Good to know. It's nor clear, since the OP is using it in `class ImageService : IImageService` which does not derive from `ControllerBase` and also, he was referencing `System.IO.File`. But probably this was part of his problem.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes which is where the problem arose. They were trying to call controller methods from the service.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the `byte[]` data contains the image itself and not a path to an image file. Otherwise `Data` would simply be a string. You can convert this to an `Image` object with

```
Image image;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the context under which the OP is related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that

```
return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(MyArtistImage.Data ...
```