# How do I return a file stored as byte[] in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, filestream

I've been searching for a while and while it should be simple, I just can't get it to work. Based on examples I've seen, this is where I got so far:

**SomeAppService.cs**

```
public async Task<FileStream> Download(long? id)
{
    var attachment = await _repository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    var fileStream = new FileStream($"{attachment.FileName}.{attachment.FileExtension}", 
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    fileStream.Write(attachment.File, 0, attachment.File.Length);

    return fileStream;
}
```

As it can be noticed, "FileName", "FileExtension" and "File" (which is the forementioned byte array) are stored in a database. The attachment can be any kind of file, save for banned extensions in the Upload method (not shown). Then in my controller I have:

**SomeController.cs**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("Download/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(long? id)
{
    var fileStream = await appService.Download(id);
    return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

However, when I hit the download endpoint, I end up with a file named "response", no extension, with 0 bytes.

Resources:

[Return file in ASP.Net Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460198/return-file-in-asp-net-core-web-api)

[Return a FileResult from a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093166/return-a-fileresult-from-a-byte)

[Save and load MemoryStream to/from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file) (Response with 255 upvotes gave me de idea of how to turn a byte array into a filestream, but I don't know if that works)

Comment: You probably need to reset the position of the stream to the beginning. However it seems you could just wrap `attachment.File` in a `MemoryStream` and pass that to the `FileStreamResult` constructor directly. There's also a [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_FileContentResult__ctor_System_Byte___System_String_) you could pass `attachment.File` to instead of creating a stream.

Comment: The `FileStream` `return`ed by `Download()` will be positioned immediately after the data you've just written.  Does `Seek()`ing back to the beginning of the `Stream` before `return`ing it produce a different result?

Comment: With a File you offer for download, stuff like the (prefered) filenmane and lenght (edit: and position too) have to be explicitly specified. I do not know of that pattern myself, I only ever used HTTP handlers: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/working-with-image-in-httphandler/ and even that a while ago.

Comment: @BACON Just tried it. No dice.

Comment: something like this, `return File(byteArray, "contentType");`  content type is for example `application/pdf`

Comment: Though it looks like the posted answers offer better solutions, I'd just add that your `FileStream` was opened with `FileAccess.Write` rights, so it couldn't be used to read the file back again. Perhaps if you provided the controller its own stream with `return new FileStream($"{attachment.FileName}.{attachment.FileExtension}", 
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` (don't forget to close the one used to create the file) the `FileStream` approach would work. (That presumes that somewhere outside your code an empty file is returned if it cannot be read, which I don't know to be true.)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks everyone, in the end `FileContentResult` did the trick.

This is how it looks:

**Service**

```
public async Task<Attachment> Download(long? id)
{
    return await _repository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("Download/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(long? id)
{
    var attachment = await appService.Download(id);
    return new FileContentResult(attachment.File, 
        MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(attachment.FileExtension))
    {
        FileDownloadName = $"{attachment.NomeFile}.{attachment.FileExtension}"
    };
}
```

`MimeTypeMap` can be found [here](https://github.com/samuelneff/MimeTypeMap)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stream a file from a database blob from entity framework without loading it into memory. First split the data model into two parts;

```cs
public class Attachment{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public virtual AttachmentBlob Blob { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class AttachmentBlob{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Map them to the same table, but not as an owned type;

```cs
   modelBuilder.Entity<Attachment>(e => {
       e.HasOne(a => a.Blob)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey<AttachmentBlob>(b => b.Id);
   });
   modelBuilder.Entity<AttachmentBlob>(e => {
       e.ToTable("Attachment");
   });
```

Then you can read and write them either as byte arrays, or as streams;

```cs
   public static async Task Read(DbContext db, Attachment attachment, Func<Stream,Task> callback)
   {
      await db.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
      try {
         var conn = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
         var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
         var parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
         cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
         parm.ParameterName = "@id";
         parm.Value = attachment.Id;
         cmd.CommandText = "select File from Attachment where Id = @id";
         using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()){
            if (await reader.ReadAsync())
               await callback(reader.GetStream(0));
         }
      } finally {
         await db.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
      }
   }

   public class AttachmentResult : FileStreamResult
   {
      private readonly DbContext db;
      private readonly Attachment attachment;

      public AttachmentResult(DbContext db, Attachment attachment) : base(new MemoryStream(), attachment.ContentType)
      {
         this.db = db;
         this.attachment = attachment;
      }

      public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
      {
         await Read(db, attachment, async s => {
            FileStream = s;
            await base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
         });
      }
   }

   public static async Task Write(DbContext db, Attachment attachment, Stream content)
   {
      await db.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
      try {
         var conn = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
         var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
         cmd.Transaction = db.Database.CurrentTransaction?.GetDbTransaction();
         var parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
         cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
         parm.ParameterName = "@id";
         parm.Value = attachment.Id;
         parm = cmd.CreateParameter();
         cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
         parm.ParameterName = "@content";
         parm.Value = content;
         cmd.CommandText = "update Attachment set File = @content where Id = @id";
         await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
      } finally {
         await db.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
      }
   }

   public static Task InsertAttachment(DbContext db, Attachment attachment, Stream content){
      var strat = db.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
      return strat.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
         using (var trans = await db.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
         {
             db.Set<Attachment>.Add(attachment);
             await db.SaveChangesAsync();
             await Write(db, attachment, content);
             trans.Commit();
             db.ChangeTracker.AcceptAllChanges();
         }
      });
   }
```

Comment: This method can also be adapted to large strings with `reader.GetTextReader()` or `parm.Value = [TextReader]`.